# Show that $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{align}
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
t^2 & t\leq 0\\
0 & t\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq 0\\
t^2 & t\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Consider the expression
\begin{align}
\lambda_{1} f+\lambda_{2} g=0
\end{align}

For $t<0$, $g(t)=0$ , so the expression has a non-trivial solution.

For $t\geq0$, $f(t) = 0$ , so the expression also has a non-trivial solution.

How do i show that $f$ and $g$ are indeed linearly independent?

What went wrong in my reasoning above?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent, then they must be scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: i know of this, but im asking what went wrong with my reasoning above

Comment: For $t<0$ we have $$0=\lambda_1f(t)+\lambda_2g(t)=\lambda_1t^2+\lambda_2\cdot 0=\lambda_1t^2$$ which means $\lambda_1=0$. Similarly $\lambda_2=0$. Thus $\lambda_1f+\lambda_2g=0$ if and only if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$, i.e. $f,g$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Why couldn't $\lambda_{2} \neq 0$ ? Any scalar multiplication on the $0$ constant function has no effect.

Comment: Because for $t>0$ we have $$0=\lambda_1f(t)+\lambda_2g(t)=\lambda_1\cdot 0+\lambda_2t^2=\lambda_2t^2.$$ This forces $\lambda_2=0$.

Comment: I see, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome:)

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent iff there are constants $A, B$ , not both $0,$ such that $Af(t)+Bg(t)=0$ for ALL $t.$